# Проблема с ошибкой 'NoneType' object is not iterable в цикле while

Tags: python

Всех приветствую. Задача - пользователь вводит числа сколько угодно раз, при этом 0 - осуществляет выход из программы. После окончания ввода необходимо просчитать и вывести среднее значение введенных чисел.

```
numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')

while numb != '0':
    num_list = []
    num_list = num_list.append(numb)
    
    if numb == 'end':
        avg = ()
        avg = sum(num_list) / len(num_list)
        print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {avg}') 
        break
    numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
```

При инициализации кода выдается ошибка **'NoneType' object is not iterable**. Не понимаю, почему получается значение **None** и откуда она выскакивает. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `num_list.append(numb)` -> ничего не возвращает, т.е. возвращает `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код содержит несколько ошибок.

1. `num_list` стирается в цикле. Данные не накапливаются.
2. В `num_list` добавляются строки, не числа. Суммировать такой список
   не имеет смысла.
3. Оператор `num_list = num_list.append(numb)` замещает список на
   значение `None`. Распространённая ошибка.

Если поправить эти ошибки, получится такой код. У него только один недостаток - он ломается если сразу ввести `end`:

```
numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')

num_list = []
while numb != '0':
    
    if numb == 'end':
        avg = ()
        avg = sum(num_list) / len(num_list)
        print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {avg}') 
        break

    num_list.append(int(numb))
    numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
```

Но и этот код грешен дублированием. Устраним его:

```
num_list = []
while True:
    numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
    if numb == '0':
        break

    if numb == 'end':
        avg = ()
        avg = sum(num_list) / len(num_list)
        print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {avg}') 
        break

    num_list.append(int(numb))
```

Нужет ли список значений? Нет. Нужны только его сумма и длина. Уберем список:

```
sum_ = 0
len_ = 0
while True:
    numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
    if numb == '0':
        break

    if numb == 'end':
        avg = sum_ / len_
        print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {avg}') 
        break

    sum_ += int(numb)
    len_ += 1
```

Остались опечатки, другой порядок операторов, лишние переменные. Можно идти сдавать:

```
sum_ = 0
len_ = 0
while True:
    n = input('Введите любое целое число (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
    if n == 'end':
        print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {sum_ / len_}') 
        break

    if n == '0':
        break

    sum_ += int(n)
    len_ += 1
```

Сдавать рано, поправим ошибку когда пользователь сразу вводит `end`. Вот теперь комар носа не подточит:

```
sum_ = 0
len_ = 0
while True:
    n = input('Введите любое целое число (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
    if n == 'end':
        if len_ == 0:
            print('Вы не ввели ни одного числа')
        else:
            print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {sum_ / len_}') 
        break

    if n == '0':
        break

    sum_ += int(n)
    len_ += 1
```

Comment: Я сделал так:
` numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ')
num_list = []

while numb != '0':
    
    if num_list == [] and numb == 'end':
        print('Вы не ввели ни одного числа')
        break
    
    if numb == 'end':
        avg = ()
        avg = sum(num_list) / len(num_list)
        print(f'Среднее значение введенных чисел: {avg}') 
        break
    
    num_list.append(int(numb))    
    numb = input('Введите любое целое цисло (end для окончания ввода, 0 для выхода): ') `

Comment: Отличный вариант!

Comment: Станислав, спасибо. А почему у меня не отображается  код как положено в комментариях?

Comment: Потому что форматирование это типа не поддержано в комментариях. :( Чтобы прочитать ваш код я вставил его в редактор и отформатировал.

Comment: Странно, написано, что в комментах используется `код` для его вставки. Но не работает это) Еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

1. вы считаете сумму по строкам, а не числам - ведь `input` выводит строки:

   ```
    avg = sum(num_list) / len(num_list)
   ```
2. вы каждый этап цикла создаете пустой список, так что у вас в нем максимум 1 значение

   ```
    num_list = []
    num_list = num_list.append(numb)
   ```
3. после добавления значения в список вы переписываете список через присваивание, в итоге у вас уже не список, а `None`, а это как раз не является итерируемым объектом

поэтому запихивайте в список числа, причем запихивайте правильно:

```
num_list.append(int(numb))
```

и вынесите инициализацию списка `num_list` из цикла `while`

**P.S.**

предположу, что после окончания ввода, но до выхода из программы можно опять начать накапливать числа - а значит список `num_list` надо очистить

**P.P.S.**

если пользователь сразу введет `'end'`, то программа рухнет из-за перевода строки в число - этот момент тоже надо учесть, т.е. добавление в список должно сидеть в альтернативной ветке условия на `'end'`

Comment: Если не сразу ввести `end` то тоже рухнет. Надо менять порядок обрботки: сперва проверять на `end`, затем добавлять в список.